# Migrate nginx-proxy to docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, proxy

- Docker version 20.10.25
- Docker Compose version v2.20.2
- EC2 using Amazon Linux (Ubuntu 20)

I had inherited a project with two manually run containers ([nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) and [nginx-proxy-acme-companion](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion)):

```
docker run --detach \
    --name nginx-proxy \
    --publish 80:80 \
    --publish 443:443 \
    --volume certs:/etc/nginx/certs \
    --volume vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d \
    --volume html:/usr/share/nginx/html \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro \
    --net nginx-gateway nginxproxy/nginx-proxy

docker run --detach \
    --name nginx-proxy-acme \
    --volumes-from nginx-proxy \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    --volume acme:/etc/acme.sh \
    --env "DEFAULT_EMAIL=me@example.com VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com" \
    --net nginx-gateway nginxproxy/acme-companion
```

And two within a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn ourapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - uploads:/app/media_uploads
    expose:
      - 8001
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    entrypoint:
      - "./docker-entrypoint.sh"
    networks:
      default: {}
      nginx-gateway:
        aliases:
          - web

  nginx:
    build: ./service/nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - uploads:/app/media_uploads
    expose:
      - 8002
    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    depends_on:
      - web
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    networks:
      default: {}
      nginx-gateway:
        aliases:
          - nginx

networks:
  default:
  nginx-gateway:
      external: true
      name: nginx-gateway

volumes:
  static_volume:
  uploads:
  code:
  certs:
  vhost:
  html:
  acme:
```

At one point I updated the docker-compose file to configure all four containers and my app routed correctly with SSL using the following configuration:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      nginx-gateway:

  nginx-proxy-acme:
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy:rw
    volumes:
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
    environment:
      - ./.env
    networks:
      nginx-gateway:
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn ourapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - uploads:/app/media_uploads
    expose:
      - 8001
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
      - nginx-proxy-acme
    entrypoint:
      - "./docker-entrypoint.sh"
    networks:
      default: {}
      nginx-gateway:
        aliases:
          - web

  nginx:
    build: ./service/nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - uploads:/app/media_uploads
    expose:
      - 8002
    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    depends_on:
      - web
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    networks:
      default: {}
      nginx-gateway:
        aliases:
          - nginx

networks:
  default:
  nginx-gateway:
      external: true
      name: nginx-gateway

volumes:
  static_volume:
  uploads:
  code:
  certs:
  vhost:
  html:
  acme:
```

I had added the `depends_on` key for the `web` container that runs our Django app.

However, after restarting the server and updating packages, the nginx-proxy doesn't seem to be exposing the proxied containers (*unless* I revert back to manually running the proxy containers).

### Troubleshooting:

#### From inside the `web` container:

##### Django app is responding.

```
curl localhost:8001
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bad Request (400)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bad Request (400)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

### Inspecting the container IPs:

`docker inspect --format='{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)`

#### When launching the two proxies manually:

```
/nginx-proxy-acme - 172.21.0.3
/nginx-proxy - 172.21.0.2
/ourapp-nginx-1 - 172.22.0.3172.21.0.5
/ourapp-web-1 - 172.22.0.2172.21.0.4
```

#### With all four containers by docker-compose.

```
/ourapp-nginx-1 - 172.23.0.3172.21.0.3
/ourapp-web-1 - 172.23.0.2172.21.0.4
/ourapp-nginx-proxy-acme-1 -
/ourapp-nginx-proxy-1 - 172.21.0.2
```

NOTE: `ourapp-nginx-proxy-acme-1` isn't running,

```
docker exec ourapp-nginx-proxy-acme-1 cat /etc/hosts
Error response from daemon: Container e8a1...36be0 is not running
```

but I'm not sure if that matters (as it only needs to run when needed to renew certificate.)

If just found my way to these [acme-companion docker-compose docs](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion/blob/main/docs/Docker-Compose.md) and will report back (possibly with a solution) when I have a chance to compare the examples to mine.

In the meantime, as always, input (as well as votes to close) are welcome.

Thanks.